# remote jms client for jboss 7.1.1

Tags: client, jms

I am trying to integrate a standalone remote JMS client running in a SE context with JBoss 7.1.1 running on a different server. Right now, it is failing when I try to obtain an InitialContext.

My questions are:

What are the client libraries needed? Do I need all the jars in the jboss-as-jms-client-bom? Can someone provide a simple example of setting up a subscription to a topic.

This is the code I am using:

```
    final Properties env = new Properties();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://myremotehost:4447");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "username");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");
    Context initialContext = new InitialContext(env);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can find all dependencies with maven with just few clicks. Creates a Maven project and add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-jms-client-bom</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
```